# Vertically center objects in colored box

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, alignment, box

I want to create a structure like in the image below.

[image]

That's a colored box, which should be at a defined distance from the top of the page. In the box, I want to show a picture on the left side and print an arbitrary number of lines on the right. I'm going to compile a lot of documents and therefore I'm going to automate this process (the text content is read from a json with `luacode`). The pictures I use won't all have the same size and also the number of points in the text varies between documents. So in another case, I want it to look like this:

[image]

The key point is, that both the picture and the text block on the right are vertically centered around the center of the colored box.
I tried doing this by embedding a `tabular` in another `tabular`, but this way I didn't get the picture centered. Currently. I'm drawing the box simply with

```
\filldraw[green] ($(current page.north west)+(0cm,-16cm)$) rectangle  ($(current page.south east)+(0cm,4cm)$);
```

and I don't know how to link the box position to the objects within it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're willing to use tikz so I tried to arrange boxes and their as you might wish (provided I correctly got what you need):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,fit}
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (sw) at ($(current page.north west)+(0cm,-16cm)$);
\coordinate (ne) at ($(current page.south east)+(0cm,4cm)$);
\node[fit={(ne)(sw)},fill=green!10](colorbox){};
\node[draw,minimum size =4cm](pic)at({$(colorbox.north west)!1/3!(colorbox.north east)$}|-{$(colorbox.south west)!1/2!(colorbox.north west)$}){PIC};
\node[draw,text width=\linewidth/3](text)at({$(colorbox.north west)!2/3!(colorbox.north east)$}|-{$(colorbox.south east)!1/2!(colorbox.north east)$}){
\begin{itemize}
\item[•] cats have four legs
\item[•]
\item[•]
\item[•] there's much more to say about cats , so I need automatic linebreaks
\item[•]
\item[•] cats have four legs
\item[•]
\item[•]
\item[•] there's much more to say about cats , so I need automatic linebreaks
\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces :

[image]

Comment: Instead of `\item[•]` you can write just `\item`, recent LaTeX has integrated `utf8` encoding, ...

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it helped me a lot! After a bit of trying I managed to adapt your code to my needs. The last thing I didn't find out: how can I actually remove the frame around picture and itemize block?

Comment: also, the position of the colored box changes depending on the width of the image. Is that supposed to happen? Isn't the position set absolute and deterministic in your code?

Comment: The default anchor is the center of the picture.  You can change that using [anchor=...].

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without the machinery of TiKZ, only the small `framed` package and its `shaded` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} %
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{framed, linegoal}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{LimeGreen}

\begin{document}

\begin{shaded}
\sffamily
\includegraphics[scale=0.4, valign=c]{kingsize_canary}
\quad\begin{minipage}[c]{\linegoal}
\begin{itemize}
\item cats have four legs
\item cats don’t like dogs (and conversely)
\item cats eat birds \& mice
\item there's much more to say about cats , so I need automatic linebreaks
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This measures the picture's size and adapts the textual part width. Fix the paddings to your liking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\newsavebox{\picturetextbox}
\newsavebox{\picturebox}
\newcommand{\picturebgcolor}{}% initialize

\newenvironment{picturetext}[4][]
 {% #1 options for the picture
  % #2 picture file name
  % #3 background color
  % #4 global width
  \renewcommand{\picturebgcolor}{#3}%
  \sbox{\picturebox}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\picturetextbox}
  \hspace{1em}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\usebox{\picturebox}\end{tabular}%
  \hspace{1em}%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr#4-5em-\wd\picturebox\relax}\raggedright
 }
 {%
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}%
  \colorbox{\picturebgcolor}{\usebox{\picturetextbox}}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{picturetext}[width=5cm]{example-image}{green}{\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item cats eat meat
  \item there's much more to say about cats, so I need automatic linebreaks
  \item there's much more to say about cats, so I need automatic linebreaks
  \item there's much more to say about cats, so I need automatic linebreaks
  \end{itemize}
\end{picturetext}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{picturetext}[width=2cm]{example-image-9x16}{green}{0.75\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item cats eat meat
  \item there's much more to say about cats, so I need automatic linebreaks
  \end{itemize}
\end{picturetext}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]